# Почему создается пустой список?

Tags: python-3.x

[image: вот, в примере водятся две матрицы через enter]

И у меня с таким кодом в матрице `b` создается пустой первый список.

Как этого избежать?

Мой код, в котором я пытался это реализовать:

```
n,m =  [int(d) for d in input().split()]
A = []
for i in range(n):
    row = input().split()
    for k in range(len(row)):
        row[k] = int(row[k])
    A.append(row)
sum = 0
B = []
for i in range(n):
    row = input().split()
    for k in range(len(row)):
        row[k] = int(row[k])
    B.append(row)
for i1 in range(n):
    for i2 in range(n):
        if B[i1][i2] == 1:
            sum = sum + A[i1][i2]
print(sum)
```

Comment: я первый раз пользуюсь так что там не видно, но проблема в том что вот если скопировать данные с примера то там из за enter во 2 матрице создается пустой список

Comment: вставьте лишний input для чтения пустой строки